# C++11 += operator not working when RHS has more than one string or character

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-concatenation

I am using `c++11`. When I use the `+=` operator for concating strings or characters, it does not work, however `=`, works.

e.g. I used all the below test cases independently, i.e. separately.

```
    string s="abdddddd";
    string ss="";
    ss+=s[0];//working
    ss+=s[0]+s[1]; //not working     output: Ã
    ss+="hi"+s[2];  //not working      no output
    ss+='d'+'c';  //not working      output: З
    ss+="hi"+"string"; //not working  error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [3]’ and ‘const char [7]’ to binary ‘operator+’

    string another="this";
    ss+=another+'b'; //working
    ss+="hi"+another;//working
    ss+=("hi"+s[3]); //not working
    ss=ss+"hi"+s[3]; //working
    ss=ss+"hi"+"this"; //working
```

Also adding brackets doesn't work.  So, I want to know why it doesn't work with strings, it works with adding integers.

Comment: Think about what each element of `s` really is, and what literal strings like `"hi"` decays to. Then think about how adding two bytes together would create a valid string, or what happens when you add a pointer and a byte together.

Comment: `ss += "hi" + "string";`: does this compile?

Comment: @Jabberwocky no.

Comment: Did you understand the error message for `ss += "hi" + "string";` ?

Comment: Should be using `std::stringstream` (which makes everything easy in this scenario), or be using `"hi"s` string literals, or wrapping in `string("hi")` for C-style strings or `string(1, 'c')` for single character.  Cannot expect string concatenation operations on non-string objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not `+=`, it is `+`.

For example in the line `ss+=s[0]+s[1];`, `s[0]` and `s[1]` are of type `char`. Adding them will add their integer representations (ASCII codes) and concatenate the character this sum represents to `ss`.

You see the same happing in `ss+='d'+'c';`, where you are giving `char` literals explicitly.

Only use `+` to concatenate `std::string` with `std::string` or one `std::string` with a character or string literal. You cannot concatenate two string literals or two characters or a string literal with a character. (In all of these cases `+` has different semantics than string concatenation or isn't even valid syntax.)

Comment: Why `ss=ss+"hi"+s[3]` works? Also if I can use `a="b"+"c"`, why can't use `a+="b"+"c"`?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav - because the `ss` on the rhs is a `std::string` and because '+' is left associative.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav to expand on @mhhollomon comment: `ss=ss+"hi"+s[3]` is treated as `ss=((ss+"hi")+s[3])` so for each `+` left operand is a `std::string`.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav You can't use `a="b"+"c"` either. It will result in the same error you got for `ss+="hi"+"string";`. `ss=ss+"hi"+s[3]` works because of the operator associativity as explained by the comments above.

Comment: @uneven_mark if I use `string2="something"`, and use this string `string2`, then it works.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav Yes, if you declare `string2` with type `string`, it will work. The problem here is that *at least one side of the `+` needs to be of type `string`*. A character literal (such as `'c'`) or a string literal (such as `"hi"`) is **not** of type `string`.